# How to Debug Python in PyCharm for Buildin CGI Server

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, pycharm, remote-debugging

I run python3.6 build in CGI server on my computer(windows 7 64bit) with this command:

> python -m http.server --cgi

and I put a index.py file in ./cgi-bin/ directory.

it work well when I visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/cgi-bin/index.py on my browser.

and then I want to debug this index.py in PyCharm, but I don't know how to do it.

since it not a remote server, I can't add a remote server on PyCharm to debug it.

Comment: Did you try [Attach to process](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/attaching-to-local-process.html) or [Python Debug Server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging.html#python-debug-server)? Both work fine on the local machine.

Comment: @Pavel Karateev, Thanks, I try Remote Debugging, and it work. But there is problem, the python script doesn't stop at the breakpoint. It stop at the first few line at the python script, and then I have to press F6 to make the debug process, but when I enter F8, it doesn't suspend at the next breakpoint, it just run to the end of the python script. I post a question about it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590628/when-remote-debug-buildin-cgi-server-on-pycharm-python-script-doesnt-stop-at-b