# When Remote Debug Buildin CGI Server on PyCharm, Python Script Doesn't Stop at Breakpoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pycharm, remote-debugging

My environment: Windows7 64bit, Python 3.6.4 64bit, PyCharm 5.0.4,
the version of pydevd I install was 1.1.1

I config Python Remote Debug on PyCharm, using port 8001,

and add this code to my cgi-bin/index.py:

```
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace('127.0.0.1', port=8001)
```

then I visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/cgi-bin/index.py, PyCharm show that debug suspend at the line right behind the code:

```
pydevd.settrace('127.0.0.1', port=8001)
```

I could enter F6 or F5 to step over code or step into code like I normally do, but when I enter F8, PyCharm didn't stop at the next breakpoint like usual, it run the whole index.py instead.

Comment: One should not install `pydevd` from PyPI, Python Debug Server requires pre-bundled egg from `<pycharm_installation_folder>/debug-eggs`.

Comment: @Pavel Karateev, you are right. I unistall pydevd, then just add the path of the pycharm-debug-py3k.egg in PyCharm Folder to PYTHONPATH, and I can use F8 to debug my script.